# Is it possible use a conditional jump to jump to $ra in mips?

Tags: mips

For example in a while loop like:

```
whileloop1:
       sll $t3, $t1, 2        # i * 4
       move $t4, $a1          # temp = base address of a
       add $t4, $t4, $t3      # move the address of a[i]
       lw $t5, ($t4)          # store a[i] in temp
       bge $t5, $t0, $ra      # if a[i] >= p return 
       addi $t1, $t1, 1       # add 1 to i
       j whileloop1           #restart loop
```

where it would link back to a function like this:

```
differentlabel:
                #some code
                jal whileloop1
                #use results
```

Is it possible to jump back to $ra in some manner?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want a conditional `jal` or do you want a conditional `jr`?

Comment: @KonradLindenbach a conditional jr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would combine a branch and a `jr` if I wanted to create a conditional `jr`.

E.g. to branch if `$s0` equals `$s1`

```
bne $s0 $s1 dontJump
jr  $ra
dontJump:
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind of. The branch instructions in mips use *relative addressing*, which means you have to use immediate data (usually a label), not the contents of a register like `$ra`.

That being said, you could use a label and just return from there.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of such an obvious solution... I think of labels as more of a means to break the code into logical units. Forgetting that they do indeed have a function to them.